# how to Discover the IP address of Server Socket listening to the Port XX using C# Window

Tags: c#, sockets

I am making C# Server and Socket image sending application. The main problem that I am facing right now is that each and everytime when I load my client I have to specify the server's name or it's IP address.

Can I get any idea how client socket able to  get the IP Addresses of Servers listening at certain Port XX? I don't want to fix or type the IP Address manually in client side to connect to server socket.  (Sorry for my poor English)

**My Scenario** is

I have 3 tablets called A,B,C installed client app and another 3 tablet called D,E,F installed Server app. Each client can send image to each server. So Problem is I don't want to fix IP Address of server in client socket.

Comment: you will have to scan the network for that.

Comment: If you write both client and server you could consider doing a broadcast message of "Im here" from the server to pick up on the client.

Comment: @BugFinder   +broadcast message. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast using Udp socket, can send data all the ip address listening at the port. This is my client side code I sent to all the server listening at the port 4800.

```
 foreach (IPAddress ip in allLocalNetworkAddresses.AddressList)
        {
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);


            //Allow sending broadcast messages
            client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
            SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);

            //Bind on port 0. The OS will give some port between 1025 and 5000.
          //  client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 0));

            //Create endpoint, broadcast.
            IPEndPoint AllEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, Port);   
            byte[] sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1");

            client.SendTo(sendData, AllEndPoint);
            Console.Write("Client send '1' to " + AllEndPoint.ToString() +
            Environment.NewLine);
```